# initialize all the metadata at once

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Singleton class which connects to Cassandra. I want to initialize `processMetadata`, `procMetadata` and `topicMetadata` all at once not one by one. If they gets initialize all at once then I will see consistent values from all those three not different values for either of them.

In the below code, `processMetadata`, `procMetadata` and `topicMetadata` is initialized for the first time inside `initializeMetadata` method and then it gets updated every 15 minutes.

```
public class CassUtil {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getInstance(CassUtil.class);
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  // below are my three metedata which I need to update all three at once not one by one
  private List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<String> topicMetadata = new ArrayList<>();

  private Session session;
  private Cluster cluster;

  private static class Holder {
    private static final CassUtil INSTANCE = new CassUtil();
  }

  public static CassUtil getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private CassUtil() {
    List<String> servers = TestUtils.HOSTNAMES;
    String username = TestUtils.USERNAME;
    String password = TestUtils.PASSWORD;

    PoolingOptions opts = new PoolingOptions();
    opts.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,
        opts.getCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL));

    Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
    cluster =
        builder
            .addContactPoints(servers.toArray(new String[servers.size()]))
            .withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withPoolingOptions(opts)
            .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
                DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
                    .builder()
                    .withLocalDc(
                        !TestUtils.isProduction() ? "DC2" : TestUtils.getCurrentLocation()
                            .get().name().toLowerCase()).build())
            .withCredentials(username, password).build();

    try {
      session = cluster.connect("testkeyspace");
    } catch (NoHostAvailableException ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    }
  }

  // start a background thread which runs every 15 minutes
  public void startScheduleTask() {
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          processMetadata = processMetadata(true);
          topicMetadata = listOfTopic(TestUtils.GROUP_ID);
          procMetadata = procMetadata();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        }
      }
    }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }

  // called from main thread to initialize the metadata
  // and start the background thread where it gets updated
  // every 15 minutes
  public void initializeMetadata() {
    processMetadata = processMetadata(true);
    topicMetadata = listOfTopic(TestUtils.GROUP_ID);
    procMetadata = procMetadata();
    startScheduleTask();
  }

  private List<String> listOfTopic(final String consumerName) {
    List<String> listOfTopics = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select topics from topic_metadata where id=1 and consumerName=?";
    try {
        // get data from cassandra
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex), ", Consumer Name= ",
          consumerName);
    }
    return listOfTopics;
  }

  private List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata(final boolean flag) {
    List<ProcessMetadata> metadatas = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from process_metadata where id=1 and is_active=?";
    try {
        // get data from cassandra
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex), ", active= ", flag);
    }
    return metadatas;
  }

  private List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata() {
    List<ProcMetadata> metadatas = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from schema where id=1";
    try {
        // get data from cassandra
    } catch (SchemaParseException ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("schema parsing error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    }
    return metadatas;
  }

  public List<ProcessMetadata> getProcessMetadata() {
    return processMetadata;
  }

  public List<String> getTopicMetadata() {
    return topicMetadata;
  }

  public List<ProcMetadata> getProcMetadata() {
    return procMetadata;
  }
}
```

So from my main thread, I call `initializeMetadata` method only once which initializes those three metadata and then it starts a background thread which updates them every 15 minutes. Afer that I was using them like below from my multiple threads:

```
CassUtil.getInstance().getProcessMetadata();
CassUtil.getInstance().getTopicMetadata();
CassUtil.getInstance().getProcMetadata();
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I want to see same state of `processMetadata`, `topicMetadata` and `procMetadata`. Meaning these three metadata should be updated at same time not one after other bcoz I don't want to see mix state value for them after I do get on them.

How can I avoid this issue? Do I need to create another class which will hold these three metadata as constructor parameter?

Comment: What about protecting any accesses (read and write) to those fields with synchronized blocks?

Comment: let's say when the background thread gets kicked in, it will update `processMetadata` first and then it will work on `topicMetadata`. During that period, it might be possible that my get call on `processMetadata` method returns value that got updated recently but the get call on `topicMetadata` method returns old value since it is still being updated yet.. I want to avoid this and I just want to see consistent values of what was updated in each background thread run not mix of them. So I am not sure how synchronized will solve this.

Comment: Don't you think if I have a different class which takes these three metadata as constructor will solve this problem?

Comment: How will you avoid the concurrent read/writes if you simply take the code to a diff class ?

Comment: Write will only happen from a single background thread not from multiple threads but read can happen from multiple threads but for now it is also happening from single thread.

Comment: Yes it can be done with an immutable object defined as volatile in your class

Comment: All the metadata class I have are immutable classes. @NicolasFilotto can you provide me an example of how that would work basis on my example?

Comment: @david added, is clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to keep a consistent state of your lists can be to use **an immutable class** that will hold your 3 lists, you will then have a field of this type in your class that you will define `volatile` to make sure that all threads see the latest update of this field.

Here is for example the **immutable class** that we use to hold the state of the lists (it could be an ordinary class but as it is implementation specific it could be a static inner class):

```
private static class State {
    private final List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata;
    private final List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata;
    private final List<String> topicMetadata;

    public State(final List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata, 
        final List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata, final List<String> topicMetadata) {
        this.processMetadata = new ArrayList<>(processMetadata);
        this.procMetadata = new ArrayList<>(procMetadata);
        this.topicMetadata = new ArrayList<>(topicMetadata);
    }
    // Getters
}
```

Then your class would be something like that:

```
public class CassUtil {
    ...
    private volatile State state = new State(
        new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>()
    );
    ...
    public void startScheduleTask() {
        ...
                    this.state = new State(
                        processMetadata(true), listOfTopic(TestUtils.GROUP_ID), 
                        procMetadata()
                    );
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void initializeMetadata() {
        this.state = new State(
            processMetadata(true), listOfTopic(TestUtils.GROUP_ID), procMetadata()
        );
        startScheduleTask();
    }
    ...

    public List<ProcessMetadata> getProcessMetadata() {
        return this.state.getProcessMetadata();
    }

    public List<String> getTopicMetadata() {
        return this.state.getTopicMetadata();
    }

    public List<ProcMetadata> getProcMetadata() {
        return this.state.getProcMetadata();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this makes sense now. From your answer I got an idea which I implemented it and added an update in the question. Can you take a look and let me know if that will work as well? I guess with my approach, it will make sure that responsibility of CassUtil is just to populate the metadata into separate metadata class and then from reader threads, I can use that new `Metadata` class to get all the metadata I need in atomic way and also in consistent way. Does that sounds good to you? let me know your thoughts.

Comment: it is basically the same thing, so only differences are the fact that you don't rely on your singleton anymore as you now provide `static` methods and the fact that you use an `AtomicReference` which is not really necessary in your case as you only get and set so for me it is not needed. Last point please note that you did not initialize your `AtomicReference` so its value is `null` by default

Comment: `AtomicReference` is mainly interesting when you need methods like `compareAndSet`, `weakCompareAndSet`, ... if it you only get and set your value, it is only adding coupling to your class for nothing as it can be done the same way with a `volatile` field

Comment: I see so you mean to say instead of `AtomicReference` I can use volatile basically for `state` variable and everything what I have will work same way right?

Comment: yes, check the code of [`AtomicReference`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.java/#62), you will see that the value is simply a `volatile` field nothing more

Comment: Yeah you are right that's what I was looking into. So if I replace `AtomicReference` then how do I initialize my `state` variable with `Volatile` bcoz I am using `get` and `set`  method of `AtomicReference`. I don't want to rely on my singleton class for this.

Comment: With this `private static final AtomicReference<State> state = new AtomicReference<>(new State(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>()));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128971/discussion-between-david-and-nicolas-filotto).